# C# HttpClient возвращает пустую строку при POST запросе

Tags: c#, .net-core

Имеется метод для получения данных от API с помощью HttpClient.  Вроде все просто, но в результате выполнения Content пустой. Статус ответа при этом 200.
При выполнении этого же запроса через сервис проверки API все прекрасно работает - т.е. API работает. Авторизации API не требует.
RequestContent представляет собой объект содержащий данные запроса, сериализуется в `"{"action":"get","items":{"href":"/windows/releases/","what":1}}"`.

Код метода:

```
private static async Task<string> GetReleasesList(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        UseCookies = true
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            
    var requestContent = new RequestContent("get", "/windows/releases/", 1);
            
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://mkvtoolnix.download/windows/releases/", requestContent, cancellationToken);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    return text;
}
```

Класс RequestContent

````
public class RequestContent
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("action")]
            public string Action { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("items")]
            public Item Items { get; set; }

            public RequestContent(string action, string href, int what)
            {
                Items = new Item(href, what);
                Action = action;
                
            }

            public class Item
            {
                [JsonPropertyName("href")]
                public string Href { get; set; }

                [JsonPropertyName("what")]
                public int What { get; set; }

                public Item(string href, int what)
                {
                    Href = href;
                    What = what;
                }
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Проверьте заголовки используемые в стороннем сервисе API, и заголовки вашего POST запроса

Comment: Проверял - идентичные.  Собственно в стороннем сервисе из заголовков только Content-Type: application/json и Content-Length: 63
И заголовки ответа идентичные, за исключением Content-Type. В моем случае  там "text/html" а должно быть "application/json'

Comment: `Content-Type` может быть очень важен, вместо использования других заголовков лучше "расскрывать" ответ в формате json в необходимый Вам text/html. А не запрашивать напрямую используя `text/html`

Comment: 1. Если прочитаете документацию, то там сказано будет "должен быть один экземпляр класс `HttpClient` на все приложение, а вы сейчас создаете его при каждом вызове метода. 2. Заголовок `Aсcept` бесполезен. 3. `HttpClientHandler` я думаю тоже бесполезен в вашем случае. Ну и на последок, попробуйте сами сериализовать ваш `RequestContent`, будет ли та строка, которую вы ожидаете? По поводу "идентичности", чем вы проверяли? Установите, к примеру `Fiddler` и смотрите что ваша программа отправляет на сервер.

Comment: Простите, я вас не до конца понимаю. Как "раскрывать" ответ  в формате json когда содержимое ответа пустое? `response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = 0`, `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() = ""`

Comment: Переписал. Убрал `HttpClient` в статическое поле, убрал `Accept`, убрал  `HttpClientHandler`. 
Попробовал сериализовать `RequestContent`. Результат `{"action":"get","items":{"href":"/windows/releases/","what":1}}`, должно быть `{"action":"get","items":{"href":"/windows/releases/","what":1}}` На мой взгляд одинаковые.
Заголовки проверял в HTTP Debugger.
Raw идентичен Raw внешнего сервиса:
`POST /windows/releases/ HTTP/1.1
Host: mkvtoolnix.download
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 63
{"action":"get","items":{"href":"/windows/releases/","what":1}}`

Comment: В чем после дописывания кода проблема? Покажите код, где вы принимаете этот запрос. Я правильно понял, что вы отправляете в API POST запрос, а туда ничего не приходит?

Comment: Проблема в том же в чем и была - ответ приходит, но Content ответа пустой. Приходит ли что в API - сказать не могу, ибо это сторонний сервис.
`var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://mkvtoolnix.download/windows/releases/", requestContent, cancellationToken);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);`
Результат: text - пустая строка. response.Status - 200, OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо это просто примитивная защита от ботов или баг сервера. Достаточно добавить `User-Agent`.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new() { DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20 };

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0");
    var obj = new { action = "get", items = new { href = "/windows/releases/", what = 1 } };
    using var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://mkvtoolnix.download/windows/releases/", obj);
    string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(text));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
{"items":[{"href":"/","time":1639909711000,"size":null,"managed":true,"fetched":true},{"href":"/almalinux/","time":1622654036000,"size":null,"managed":true,"fetched":false},{"href":"/appimage/","time":1636884099000,"size":null,"managed":true,"fetched":false},{"href":"/centos/","time":1622653796000,"size":null,"managed":true,"fetched":false},{"href":"/centosstream/","time":1622890796000,"size":null,"managed":true,"fetched":false},...
```

`HttpVersion.Version20` здесь роли не играет, я просто пока отлаживал, видел что сервер поддерживает, и просто добавил в код.

Comment: Ох. Действительно. Я думал про UserAgent но меня сбило с толку то, что при выполнении запроса в простом Python скрипте данные так же получались без указания UserAgent. Возможно он там подставляется автоматически, в питоне не специалист ни разу.
Спасибо огромное